# how to rectify the warning for extended permission in ios

Tags: ios, fb-graph

```
-(void)authenticateUserWithCallbackObject:(id)anObject andSelector:(SEL)selector andExtendedPermissions:(NSString *)extended_permissions:(id)aDelegate
{
    DelegateObj = aDelegate;
    UIWindow* window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    if (!window) 
    {
        window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    [self authenticateUserWithCallbackObject:anObject andSelector:selector andExtendedPermissions:extended_permissions andSuperView:window];
}
```

I am getting a warning in FBGraph saying "extended_permissions used as name of previous parameter rather than as part of selector" how do i solve this warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method signature is misspelled:

```
-(void)authenticateUserWithCallbackObject:(id)anObject andSelector:(SEL)selector andExtendedPermissions:(NSString *)extended_permissions:(id)aDelegate
```

Maybe you meant something like:

-(void)authenticateUserWithCallbackObject:(id)anObject andSelector:(SEL)selector andExtendedPermissions:(NSString *)extended_permissions **andDelegate**:(id)aDelegate